# How to use "then" as a modifier

Tags: punctuation

Which would you use or expect to see?

1. "Iggy accidently caught me in the eye when he was hugging a then friend, Howard Devoto."
2. "Iggy accidently caught me in the eye when he was hugging a, then, friend, Howard Devoto."
3. "Iggy accidently caught me in the eye when he was hugging a then-friend, Howard Devoto."
4. "Iggy accidently caught me in the eye when he was hugging a (then) friend, Howard Devoto."

Comment: Number two and four are complete nonstarters. How did you even come up with these, and why? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/then#Adjective

Comment: This version of 'then' is sometimes called a syntactically non-predicative adjective' ([Coppock](http://eecoppock.info/CoppockThesis5.pdf)), this particular one, like 'now', 'future', 'former' and 'late' (= 'deceased) being used to show the time frame within which the statement was / is / is going to be (from the time of writing) true. These adjectives (as they are usually classed) are punctuated like more central attributive ones. Your (1) and (4) would be acceptable.

Comment: I must, I'm afraid, disagree with RegDwight, option 4 is perfectly acceptable.  Option 1 is fine and I can see the logic behind option 3 but I would certainly not go with option 2.

Comment: Mar, in forming example sentences, trim away irrelevancies like “Iggy accidently caught me in the eye when” and  “Howard Devoto”, that in any case are exactly the same in all four instances.  -1 for including all that clutter.  Note, the clutter makes it obvious that nobody would expect to see any of these sentences, nor would use them.

Answer (score 0):

In Heidegger's Early Philosophy: The Phenomenology of Ecstatic ..., Volume 49, I found "then" used as an adjective in a darling way... modifying 'thing.'  It looks like this:  "This is not a 'then-thing' outside to which it would be related..."   You can see the context there.  The author is speaking of a "then-thing" as a way of saying NOW in the story without saying NOW as the reader is reading in a real time way. I like it and the way it is punctuated with the single apostrophes and the dash between the two words.